# Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) { name: 'MongoNetworkError', insertedDocs:

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Please help with this insertMany error. This is a MEAN stack project.

**THIS CODE WORKS WITH SAME SIZE OF COLLECTION WHEN I TRY IT ON MY LAPTOP. BUT WHEN THIS IS EXECUTED ON THE VPS IT GIVES ERROR.**

There are two mongoDb collections: pmlaDb and pmlaDraftDb. The pmlaDraftDb gets populated when user uploads multiple CSV files(one at a time). The number of records in pmlaDraftDb at the moment is 800,000+. And this will increase a lot in future.

When needed the pmlaDb needs to be replaced by pmlaDraftDb. This is done by first deleting all records from pmlaDb and then inserting records from pmlaDraftDb.

Currently the inserting of records from pmlaDraftDb into pmlaDb is done in batches of 100,000 at a time. The error occurs in `await PmlaDb.insertMany(partPmlaDraftDb);` statement.
The node method and the console output with error message is given below.

**Node Method**

```
  let pmlaDraftDb = await PmlaDraftDb.find().select('-_id -__v').lean().exec();
  if(!pmlaDraftDb) throw "Draft PMLA DB not found"

  let noOfDbs = 0;
  const dbRecordsCount = pmlaDraftDb.length;
  
  if(dbRecordsCount === 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  // console.log('sorting draft DB now by Ctrl Name');
  pmlaDraftDb.sort((a, b) => a.ctrlName.localeCompare(b.ctrlName));
  
  //console.log('adding SrNos to the draft DB');
  let ourSrNo = 0;
  pmlaDraftDb = pmlaDraftDb.map(e => {
    ourSrNo++
    e.ourSrNo = ourSrNo;
    return e
  })
  

  await PmlaDb.deleteMany();
  // console.log('Deleted All records in Active DB')

  // insertMany batches of 1,00,000
  let noOfBatches = dbRecordsCount / 100000;
  let fullNoOfBatches = Math.trunc(noOfBatches);
  if(noOfBatches > fullNoOfBatches) fullNoOfBatches++ 
  
  let stIndex = 0;
  let endIndex = 100000
  let partPmlaDraftDb;

  console.log('Starting - Inserting of Draft DB in blank Active DB');

  for(i = 0; i < fullNoOfBatches; i++) {
    if(dbRecordsCount < endIndex) endIndex = dbRecordsCount;

    console.log('Batch: ' + (i + 1));
    console.log('stIndex: ' + stIndex + ', endIndex: ' + endIndex);

    partPmlaDraftDb = pmlaDraftDb.slice(stIndex, endIndex);

    console.log('partPmlaDraftDb len', partPmlaDraftDb.length)

    await PmlaDb.insertMany(partPmlaDraftDb);   ////  ERROR HERE

    console.log('Inserted ' + partPmlaDraftDb.length + ' records in Active DB');

    stIndex = endIndex;
    endIndex = stIndex + 100000;
  }
  console.log('Completed - Inserting of Draft DB in blank Active DB');
```

Console.log  output

```
Starting - Inserting of Draft DB in blank Active DB
Batch: 1
stIndex: 0, endIndex: 100000
partPmlaDraftDb len 100000
Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  insertedDocs: [
    {
      _id: 65151e67b1b208c3027e824b,
      ctrlName: 'bseDefaulter',
      dbName: 'BSE Defaulter and Expelled',
      nameDetails: 'Member Name: 6793',
      alertDetails: 'Declaration Date: TRADEWINGS SOLUTIONS LIMITED; Remarks: 29/08/2023; Exch Notice: Expelled',
      ourSrNo: 1,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: 65151e67b1b208c3027e82ae,
      ctrlName: 'bseDefaulter',
      dbName: 'BSE Defaulter and Expelled',
      nameDetails: 'Member Name: 583',
      alertDetails: 'Declaration Date: Rajnikant Shantilal Jhaveri; Remarks: 18-03-1995; Exch Notice: Defaulter',
      ourSrNo: 100,
      __v: 0
    },
    .....
    .....
    ... 99900 more items
  ]
}
MongoError: pool destroyed
    at Pool.write (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:844:8)
    at _command (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:149:10)
    at command (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:28:5)
    at Object.query (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/query.js:70:3)
    at Server.query (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:649:16)
    at FindOperation.execute (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/find.js:38:12)
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:144:17
    at Server.selectServer (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:837:3)
    at Server.selectServer (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/topology_base.js:342:32)
    at executeWithServerSelection (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:131:12)
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:70:9
    at maybePromise (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
    at executeOperation (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:34:10)
    at Cursor._initializeCursor (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:541:7)
    at Cursor._initializeCursor (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:190:11)
    at nextFunction (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:744:10)
    at Cursor._next (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:209:5)
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:253:14
    at maybePromise (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
    at Cursor.next (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:238:12)
    at FindOneOperation.execute (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/find_one.js:29:14)
    at /root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:72:19
    at maybePromise (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
    at executeOperation (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:34:10)
    at Collection.<anonymous> (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1114:12)
    at Collection.deprecated [as findOne] (/root/demo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:611:15)
    at NativeCollection.<computed> [as findOne] (/root/demo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:244:33)
    at NodeCollection.findOne (/root/demo/node_modules/mquery/lib/collection/node.js:42:19)
```

Comment: Update: this worked when I reduced the batch size to 50,000 instead of 100,000 for the insertMany task. But is there a better way of handling this task of replicating a large collection(approx size 132MB, no of records 815,000, avg doc size 741B)